# VB6.0 Tutorial Website

Tags: vb6

Hi there? Please give me a website where I could study **VB6.0**, I want gradual steps of DatabaseConnection tutorial, like for instance is using *ADODB* or *DataControl*. Thanks! I need simple program [Search,DataEntry,Delete,Edit,View]...

Comment: Are you forced to use VB6 :D ?! Because you really should not, this soft is 12 years old!

Comment: Save yourself some time and download C# Express: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CS 

You'll find more examples and better support and it really isn't hard at all.

Comment: @slainer68, I can't help but do this. I'm unfortunately forced to use VB6 because our school uses this one. @Dan Andrews, is C#Express limited[trial]? I don't have **Serial Number** for that after the given time. I'd honestly like to save myself from being outdated. If you have some help to offer, here's my eadd: aerohn.arela@gmail.com                    Thanks loads!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this site briefly when I had to get back in the VB6 swing of things:
http://www.vbtutor.net/vb6/vbtutor.html

They also have a fairly robust database guide.

Comment: Thanks loads for this tut. This could help me.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use this site a while ago - found it quite useful and there is a database guide with it aswell
http://www.vb6.us
http://www.vb6.us/guides/vb6-database-guide

Comment: Agreed, this site was quite helpful to me in the past.